# Error While importing Schema in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, exception

Hey guys im trying to import schema from mysql vesion 5.0 to 5.1. Every time i'm trying to import schema I got this error:

Error near Drop Proceduer service_tt_yes'
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16. The table is probably corrupted.

I try to skip that procedure but error occur in next procedure.

Any solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use following command in MySQL Client

> **USE DATABASE_NAME; SOURCE [QUALIFIED-LOCATION]IMPORTED_SCHEMA.sql**

Like if you have IMPORTED_SCHEMA.sql  in D: drive then  fire following command. **Note there is no semi colon in the end**

> **SOURCE D:\IMPORTED_SCHEMA.sql**